# "Why didn't you buy some [or any] cheese?"

Tags: questions, uncountable-nouns, quantifiers, some-vs-any

As I know *some* is used for positive sentences and *any* for negative as well as question forms.
But what about negative questions?

> Why didn't you buy *any* cheese?

or

> Why didn't you buy *some* cheese?

Comment: Because *some* is also used when the question is polite or a request, using *shall, can, could* or *would*.

Comment: @Ustanak - Can you expand on that?  I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to say.  I would have said that the use of *some* or *any* depends more on whether we're talking about a count or a noncount noun than whether it's a request or not.  If we're asking someone about apples (a count noun), either "Didn't you buy some apples?" or "Didn't you buy any apples?" is correct, although I think they have slightly different shades of meaning.

Comment: @stangdon Yes, I forgot to mention the thing about countable and uncountable nouns. As you've pointed out, they have different shades of meaning.

Comment: The sentence doesn't indicate a request or offer. You should use "any", not some.

Comment: @stangdon: I'm afraid I don't quite get your comment about countable and uncountable nouns. Is "Did you buy some apples?" wrong to you? How about "Do you want some nuts?" or "Would you like some grapes?"? I'm not sure these should be considered wrong, though I definitely agree it has a different shade of meaning compare to the versions using "any".

Comment: Would these two sentences be correct?
Did you buy any water when you went shopping?
Did you buy some water when you went shopping?
Both cases are questions, if we follow the rules, the first one would be the correct one but there seems to be a slight difference in meaning, isn't there? Wouldn't both be okay?

Answer (score 1):

*What I would like to mention is based on standard English and I'm not talking about any other specific dialect.*

We use *some* in questions when we expect or encourage the answer "yes" e.g. you see your friend rubbing his eye. You say,

> What's wrong? Have you got something in your eye?

The same reasoning can be used for requests, or offers since we expect the person to give a "yes" answer as in

> would you like some tea?

In other cases, we use *any*. So if I see this question in a grammar test, I'd go with *'any'* not because it's a negative question
but because it's a question that doesn't expect an affirmative answer.

We can have a negative question that expects a positive answer as in

> Wouldn't you like some cookies?

Answer (score 1):

[some](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/some) - an ​amount or ​number of something that is not ​stated or not ​known

[any](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/any) - even the ​smallest ​amount or ​number of

Insert these definitions into the sentences, we get:

> Why didn't you buy **any** cheese?
>
> Why didn't you buy **even the smallest amount of** cheese?

and

> Why didn't you buy **some** cheese?
>
> Why didn't you by **an unstated amount of** cheese?

The expanded **some** version makes sense, but the meaning of the **any** version is exactly right.